# Открыть div по клику на другой div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть такая разметка

```html
<div class="pans-room">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="head">Название группы</div>
    <div class="row capt">
      <div>Тип товара</div>
      <div>Стоимость</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="complect">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
    <div class="complects">
      <div class="open">Скрытый текст</div>
      <div class="open">Скрытый текст</div>
      <div class="open">Скрытый текст</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

как сделать так что бы при клике на div с классом "click" открывался div с классом "open"? Соответственно должна соблюдаться очередность, т.е. кликнули по первому div "click" открылся первый div "open" кликнули по второму - первый закрылся второй открылся и т.д. Количество div не ограничено их может быть 3, а может 100. И самих блоков с дивом "pans-room" тоже может быть несколько, все это формируется динамически с помощью php. Для меня вся сложность как раз оказалась в том что заранее не известно количество дивов, может кто знает как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Надо добавлять идентификаторы. Как определить второй див?

Comment: не представляю как добавить индетификаторы, т.к. все это формируется с помощью php (динамически) как цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var $set = $('.table .click');
$('.table').on('click', '.click', function() {
  var n = $set.index(this);
  $('.complects .open').removeClass('active')
  $('.complects .open:eq(' + n + ')').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.click {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.open {
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.open.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pans-room">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="head">Название группы</div>
    <div class="row capt">
      <div>Тип товара</div>
      <div>Стоимость</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="click">Товар</div>
      <div>Цена</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="complect">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
    <div class="complects">
      <div class="open">1</div>
      <div class="open">2</div>
      <div class="open">3</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: можно еще вопрос, а как сделать что бы если блоков "pans-room" несколько, то при нажатии на click не происходил removeClass 'active' в соседних блоках, сейчас получается что если нажать на click то removeClass будет абсолютно для всех элементов, не зависимо от принадлежности разным блокам, такое возможно?